# Store the session of Facebook from WebView

Tags: java, android, session, cookies, webview

I'm trying to avoid that when a user has connected to Facebook from my webview, the next time he do it, doesn't need to put the email and password. I'm getting the cookie from the "facebook.com" domain with this sentence:

```
String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("facebook.com");
```

and storing it in a SQLite database. When the user try to connect another time to Facebook, I use this sentence after removing all another cookies:

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie("facebook.com", user_acc.getSessionCookie());
```

but doesn't work. That cookie I suppose that is not valid because the user has to put his username and his password again and after login, I get a different cookie that the one I had stored.

What I'm doing wrong? Is there another way to accomplish that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the solution. If I get all the cookies doesn't work, but if only get the m_user cookie all works fine.

Thank you Parry for your answers.

Regards.

Comment: You may have misdiagnosed the solution. I came across your post looking for exactly the same thing and I have been able to solve this without using any m_user or other facebook-specific cookie, by merely placing the 4 calls described in the class overview in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html

Comment: @uTubeFan Yeah, you are right. I've tried now and it works taking the facebook.com cookie. I don't know why that didn't work before, but now it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do this via cookie because this cookie is valid for only that session and as soon as user logout that cookie expires though you are storing that cookie in your database for facebook that cookie was never created that is why it is asking user name pwd again. I think best way is to click remember password

Comment: There are dozen or so cookies that facebook sets and only one is session cookie.

Comment: So, there is a way to avoid that the user has to login each time that he uses my application? If I don't remove the cookies, he only has to login the first time, so I thought that that information was stored as a cookie because if I remove them, it doesn't occurs.

Comment: but how will you prevent your user for not hitting logout? because as soon as user click logout the session becomes invalid so u cant achieve what you want by storing cookie in database see this post for session hijacking  http://atenlabs.com/blog/how-to-steal-facebook-authentication-cookies/

Comment: I'm programming a Facebook client and the webview only is used to retrieve the access token from Facebook, after that, the logout method I implement in my client wouldn't delete the cookies. Although the user could logout (or delete the cookie) it doesn't matter, when he would want login again the login page of Facebook would appear. I want to store the cookie to make the second and next login times faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem this is announced today check if this can work http://techcrunch.com/2010/11/03/facebook-single-sign-on/

Comment: Thanks for that, but reading about it I've notice that to use it, the user has to install the official app , but as I'm programming an alternative client, it's a bit strange to say the user that he must install the official Facebook client to use mine, don't you think the same?